# adding a new property in ansible list of dict

Tags: ansible

I wish to add a new property to an existing list of dict. And I came up with this. Can it be significantly simplified? thanks

```yaml
---
- name: test
  hosts:
    - localhost

  vars:
    orig: [ {"name": "albert"}, {"name": "bob"} ]
    gender: { "gender": "male" }

  tasks:
    - name: create a new list
      set_fact:
        modified: []

    - name: add gender
      set_fact:
        modified: "{{ modified + [( item | combine(gender))]}}"
      with_items: "{{ orig }}"

    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ modified }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the iteration *map* the filter *combine*. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        modified: "{{ orig|map('combine', gender)|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
    "modified": [
        {
            "gender": "male",
            "name": "albert"
        },
        {
            "gender": "male",
            "name": "bob"
        }
    ]
```